# Accessing items in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hashtag

I would like to collect some hashtags coming from Twitter.
Reading the documentation I need to get the Entities
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets

```
"entities":
{
    "hashtags":[],
    "urls":[],
    "user_mentions":[]
}
```

I'm currently able to access the Entities dict and the hashtags list

```
for line in iter(my_tweet_file)
    tweetionary = json.loads(line)
    print tweetionary["entities"]
    print tweetionary["entities"]["hashtags"]
```

But I'm not able to parse correctly the items inside the hashtags list, I'm interested in the text values (lin and Scot in the following example)

```
[{u'indices': [41, 45], u'text': u'lin'}, {u'indices': [55, 60], u'text': u'Scot'}]
```

I want to populate a dictionary of text extracted from hashtags list.

Thanks, Denny

Comment: Precise, what is needed. _dictionary of text extracted from hashtags list_ - this is not clear. Dictionary means, that it have key:value. What key and value is needed? Maybe you need just a list of hashtags?

Comment: How do you want your final dictionary to look like? Could you give some example keys and values? At the moment you only have hashtags, which could be stored in a list

Comment: In a first step I want to extract every hashtag, but because I then need to count a sort of frequency of them I was thinking to a dictionary like this: `code` freq_hash = {'lin':1, 'Scot':1, 'Win':3} `code`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely using the built-in [`Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

extracted = [{u'indices': [41, 45], u'text': u'lin'},
             {u'indices': [55, 60], u'text': u'Scot'}]

count = Counter([d['text'] for d in extracted])

#Note: For python 2.x remove brackets around print statements
print(count['lin'])
print(count.most_common())
```

Output:

```
1
[('Scot', 1), ('lin', 1)]
```

Comment: I'm going to document my self about Counter: anyway I still have a doubt on how to access directly the text value (lin and Scot) from a simple print like this: `code`print tweetionary["entities"]["hashtags"]....??? `code`

Comment: I have a for loop reading line by line my tweet information so how can I update the extracted structure once I'm reading other hashtags. The count = Counter(...) line will be used when the loop is finished.

Comment: What command did you use to get the `extracted` code snippet from my example? I think you can replace `for d in extracted` with `for d in <your_command_here>`. Probably `for d in tweetionary["entities"]["hashtags"]` but it's hard to tell